# How to enter a parameter in a Where clause?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, where-clause

With this VBA code I get an error:

> Too few parameters. Expected 1.

I do not know how to enter it right.

```
Dim rs_invoice As DAO.Recordset
Set rs_invoice = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE invoice_no Is Null AND company_name='" _
 & Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1) & "' AND shiped=" & "True")


If Not (rs_invoice.EOF And rs_invoice.BOF) Then
    rs_invoice.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs_invoice.EOF = True
        rs_invoice.Edit
        rs_invoice!invoice_no = invoice_number
        rs_invoice.Update

        rs_invoice.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
   'No records
End If

'Finish


rs_invoice.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs_invoice = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Comment: Couldn't you do the same thing with one SQL command along the lines of `UPDATE order_tbl SET invoice_no = " & invoice_number & " WHERE invoice_no Is Null AND company_name='" & Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1) & "' AND shiped=True`? Although I advocate the use of SQL parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks but i really dont know how to use this code can you post sample please? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA, but it looks like [What is the VBA equivalent for using Command.Prepare in ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1746897/1115360) could help you.

Comment: I got same error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with Access/DAO, but you're concatenating the parameter value into your query. With ADO your command text would look something like this instead:

```
Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE invoice_no Is Null AND company_name = ? AND shiped = True"
```

The `?` is a placeholder for a parameter value; instead of calling `OpenRecordset(sql)` directly, you need to make a `Command` and add a proper `Parameter`.

Seems DAO handles this a bit differently, see [Parameterized queries in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/95277/1188513) - surely one of the answers is applicable here. Because I don't like random ad-hoc queries hitting my databases I'd probably go with the `QueryDefs` approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96134/1188513):

> ```
> Dim qdf As Querydef
> Dim rst As Recordset
>
> 'then we'll open up the query:
> Set qdf = CurrentDB.QueryDefs(qryname)
>
> 'Now we'll assign values to the query using the parameters option:
> qdf.Parameters(0) = qryStartDate
> qdf.Parameters(1) = qryEndDate
>
> 'Now we'll convert the querydef to a recordset and run it
> Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
> ```

That would be:

```
Dim query As QueryDef
Set query = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("TheQuery")

query.Parameters(0) = Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1)

Dim result As Recordset
Set result = query.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Just realized, I've no idea how the error message is saying a parameter is *expected*, given it's an ad-hoc query. Still, a different and more robust approach can't hurt.

Comment: I have completed it with new query.. thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing. Can you try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE (invoice_no Is Null) AND (company_name='" _
 & Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1) & "' )AND (shiped=" & "True")
```

option 2:

```
dim str_test as string
str_test =     "SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE (invoice_no Is Null) AND (company_name='" & Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1) & "' )AND (shiped=" & "True")

debug.print str_test
```

What do you get in the immediate window?

option 3:

```
  "SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE (invoice_no Is Null) AND (company_name='" _
     & Me.cmb_start_company.Column(1) & "' )AND (shiped=True)"
```

option 4:
Then use the sample for here and it should work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243786(v=office.12).aspx Probably. Just make sure that you set your recordset the same way:

```
Dim dbsNorthwind As DAO.Database
Dim rstProducts As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set dbsNorthwind = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Discontinued = No " & _
         "ORDER BY ProductName"
Set rstProducts = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: @Pecurka - see option 2

Comment: i got this in immediate windows 

SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE (invoice_no Is Null) AND (company_name='Bogdanic GmbH doo') AND (shiped=True)

Comment: Cool. Now can you paste it as sql in MS Access and see whether you get some results? http://www.quackit.com/pix/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/tutorial/create_a_query_in_microsoft_access_5.png

Comment: yes i got results in query but i make this code in vba at table not in query

Comment: Well, I was simply debugging. At which line do you get the error?

Comment: just returning to your previous answer? Did you really get results from pasting the result from the immediate window as sql in MS Access?

Comment: @Pecurka see option 4. And try to make your code similar.